# How to iterate through a heterogeneous recursive value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I saw the HList package but I think that's way overkill for what I need.

I have this:

```
data a :*: b = a :*: b deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and I can prepend to it successfully with this:

```
prepend :: a -> b -> a :*: b
prepend a b = a :*: b
```

but I'd like to be able to iterate through the "list" somehow and do things with the elements but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Careful, `:*:` is now a (un)standard type in `GHC.Generics`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can already iterate through the list in two ways:

```
ghci> let hetlist = (1 :: Int) :*: ("two" :: String) :*: (3.0 :: Double) :*: ()
ghci> hetlist
((1 :*: "two") :*: 3.0) :*: ()
ghci> hetlist == hetlist
True
```

You can mimic this using your own typeclasses:

```
class DoStuff a where
  dostuff :: a -> a

instance DoStuff Int    where dostuff i = 2*i
instance DoStuff String where dostuff s = s ++ s
instance DoStuff Double where dostuff d = d / 2
instance DoStuff ()     where dostuff () = ()

instance (DoStuff a, DoStuff b) => DoStuff (a :*: b) where
  dostuff (a :*: b) = dostuff a :*: dostuff b
```

And then iterating over the collection is automatic

```
ghci> dostuff hetlist
((2 :*: "twotwo") :*: 1.5) :*: ()
```

Alternately, you could do much the same using `ExistentialQuantification` and wrapper types, 
and then you wouldn't have to define your own list type.

```
data DoStuffWrapper = forall a. (DoStuff a) => DoStuffWrapper a
homlist = [ DoStuffWrapper (1 :: Int)
          , DoStuffWrapper ("two" :: String)
          , DoStuffWrapper (3.0 :: Double) 
          ]
homlist' = map (\(DoStuffWrapper a) -> DoStuffWrapper (dostuff a)) homlist
```

Comment: .oO( Haskell's type system is so advanced it can make functions be not first class ;) Yay expression problem!

Answer (score 5):

The [HList paper](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=10291914512858932162) as well as the [grapefruit-records paper](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?cluster=10611101350093819205) might be of use, here.

Basic iteration is relatively simple (provided you're comfortable thinking in what's essentially Prolog), matching a record by element type (or label) is where things get hairy: Doing something depending on type equality currently demands `OverlappingInstances`, and you won't be able to decide equality on (most? all?) polymorphic types.

Matching on types might well be what you need to "do something with the elements", depending on what something is; Deletion is easy, applying a function, where its argument has to match the element type, is not trivial, but should be possible to do without compiler extensions, provided you can give the numeric index of the element.

(EDIT: This assumes that you want to apply a first class function to your list. Rampion's answer shows how to easily match on types using vanilla typeclasses, but typeclasses can't be passed around as values.)

So, in the end, it might turn out that HList or grapefruit-records isn't overkill, after all.

Comment: Seconding @barsoap's advice. If you really need extensibility, it might be difficult to be simpler than HList. The HList paper (or certainly a draft) comments that it is easier to have Nil in the type-level list than to omit it. The definition of :*: in the question is just pair, thus doesn't have Nil.